# Can't use .env file js

Tags: javascript, typescript, environment-variables, frontend

I have a project with front and server in one directory and use .env in root, that looks like

project
**frontend**(dir)
**server**(dir)
.env(file)
So, in server I use process.env.PORT and it work, but when I try to use process.env['PORT'] on front, it gives me "undefined".

When I type my variables, it gives me hints
[image]

but when I log it, it's undefined

[image]

Comment: I use Ubuntu and Webstorm IDE

Answer (score 3):

`process` is a Node variable, it doesn't exist in the browser

I'm gonna take a wild guess and say you're using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). That only populates `process.env` that lives in the server. To expose env variables in your client code, you'll have to import it, but for us to guide you there you'll have to add additional infos on how your client code is built

Personally I like to have an `env.json` at the root of my project instead of dotenv + .env and whenever I want to use variables from there I just import the file. No dotenv required, works client side and server side alike